# How do i do a case insensitive mysql contains string

Tags: mysql

I am doing a query that needs to search if the work software is in the string...the only problem is that it maybe upper or lower case so i was thinking of doing this

```
and (cd.name LIKE '%software%' or cd.name LIKE '%Software%' )
```

but i feel like there is another way if anyone knows

Comment: Possibly "%oftware%"? Of course that might clash with any number of similarities...

Answer (score 8):

MySQL is case insensitive.

These will give the same results, so you can use either:
cd.name LIKE '%software%' 
cd.name LIKE '%Software%'

That's what the 'ci' is for in the different collations (latin1_general_ci, latin1_swedish_ci)

Comment: unless its a *_bin collation, but you can still specify which collation should be used in the query, even if column in question uses case sensitive one.

Answer (score 8):

You can always try

```
LOWER(cd.name) LIKE '%software%'
```

Comment: How to use it with a Python query string?

Comment: @parsecer, this is worth its own question. If crating your own SQL string you can use the SQL LOWER function in it. If you are doing a parameter based query, just use Python's `string.lower()` to lower case the string before feeding it into the parameter.